# How can I upload jpg files into one common long horizontal image?

Tags: php, html, css

I write an image gallery and I don't use any libraries. I upload jpg files from the specific directory. I want assemble uploaded "uniq_image" images into one long horizontal image "moving_image" in order to scroll them together

The css file:

```
//the common long horizontal image that I want to assemble from uniq_images
#moving_image  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    position: relative;
    border:1px dashed red;
    width: 420px;
    height: 130px;
    left: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
//the style for each uploaded image from the file
#uniq_image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:1px solid blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The html file with php upload code inside it:

```
....
<td width ="420" height="130" overflow="hidden">
     <div id= "moving_image" >
         <?php
             $img_folder = 'picture';
             $dir = dir($img_folder);
             while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false){
                 echo '<img src="'.$img_folder."/".$file.'" style="uniq_image" >';
             }
            $dir->close();
          ?>
      </div>
<td>
```

What do I miss here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing only the basics it seems.

You should define a class style with `.uniq_image`. `#uniq_image` is a rule for an ID and you may not have multiple elements with the same ID.

And change `style="uniq_image"` to `class="uniq_image"`. The `style` property is for defining inline style rules.

There may be other issues as well, but start with these changes. Also please consider some more reading before going into implementing stuff like this, because you have everything mixed up.

Comment: Hi Alin Purcaru. You are right, thanks. It looks much better, but I still have a small issue with it. In the "moving_image" there only part of uploaded of "uniq_images". Instead of 14 images, in the "moving_image" there are only 5. I removed "overflow:hidden" from "moving_image" definition ,but the bug is still there. Do you have any idea how can I insert all images instead of only 5?

Comment: @tatiana_c You also have `overflow=hidden` on the `td`.

Comment: I also put attention to it. But if I remove "overflow:hidden" from "td" definition, the images are not wrapped into the cell and cell's size is huge instead of 420px.

Comment: I think that other issue that I asked about this is different subject from the question. Probably I'll ask other question about. Thank you very much, it very  helped me.

Comment: If you are attempting to create a tall image from many images, stacked on one another then try to float all the images in the direction you want while clearing the float immediately after the call. This will cause them to instead of line up side by side, to stack. I.e your img class will have float: right and then immediately below AND in the same class clear:float

Comment: Hi HenryGuy, thanks. I don't familiar with command "float". I tried now to add "float:right" to "moving_image" in its css definition, but it didn't change anything. Where should I add it?

Comment: I'll try to ask as a new question.